# Modifying arrays from an input then returning an output

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I'm trying to get an array I've called `input` and loop over it.

If any values are odd numbers then they get multiplied by 2.

If any are even they get divided by 2 and are then pushed to an output array which I can then return.

So far I have this, (using `cmd` node):

```
function modify(input) {
    var output = [];
    for (i=0; i=input.length; i++) {
        if (input % 2 == 1) {
            input*2;
            output.push[input];
        }
        if (input % 2 == 0) {
            input/2;
            output.push[input];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

module.exports.modify = modify;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I see in your code:

- You're not getting the values out of `input`, and you're using the entire array instead.
- Your for loop's terminating condition is set wrong (should be `i < input.length`)
- You're not assigning the result of your operations (`input*2` and `input/2`) back into the value. Even if you weren't referencing the array itself, you'd be inserting an unmodified value.
- You're using brackets instead of parentheses when you call `push()`

Try this instead:

```
function modify(input) {
    var output = [];
    for (i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        var inval = input[i];
        if (inval % 2 == 1) {
            inval = inval*2;
            output.push(inval);
        } else {
            inval = inval/2;
            output.push(inval);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you never access the elements of `input`, just the array itself. Your `if (input % 2 == 1)` line checks if *the array* mod 2 is equal to 1. That doesn't make sense, as you can't really do math on an array.

You need to do this per-element, so the minimal change would be to use `input[i]` within the loop.

There are a number of other changes you can make, and some idiomatic patterns that can make the code nicer. If you're on a recent browser and have `forEach` or `map`, you can replace the loop with a construct like:

```
var output = input.map(function (it) {
    if (it % 2 == 1) return it * 2;
    if (it % 2 == 0) return it / 2;
});
```

That can still be cleaned up, as `x % 2` can only ever return `0` or `1`, so you can replace the second condition with an `else` or just assume it returned 0:

```
var output = input.map(function (it) {
    if (it % 2 == 1) return it * 2;
    return it / 2;
});
```

Because of how JS handles true and false, specifically converting numbers, you can omit the `== 1` (`1` is truthy), and swap the condition for a ternary:

```
var output = input.map(function (it) {
    return (it % 2) ? it * 2 : it / 2;
});
```

Since you're wrapping this into a function, if you're using `map` then `output` isn't strictly necessary, so you can do:

```
module.exports.modify = function (input) {
    return input.map(function (it) {
        return (it % 2) ? it * 2 : it / 2;
    });
};
```

If you have ES6 support (likely through [the brilliant 6to5 project](http://6to5.org/)), you can replace the function declarations with arrow functions:

```
module.exports.modify = (input) => {
    return input.map((it) => {
        return (it % 2) ? it * 2 : it / 2;
    });
};
```

And if you want to get really academic with it, you can remove the `return` statements (thanks to arrow functions):

```
module.exports.modify = input => input.map(it => it % 2 ? it * 2 : it / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
for (i=0; i=input.length; i++) {
      if (input % 2 == 1) {
```

`input` is the entire array. You can't modulo an array by 2.

You need to check individual elements with the `[]` operator:

```
if (input[i] % 2 == 1) ...
```

The same applies inside the bodies of the `if` condition:

```
        input*2;
        output.push[input];
```

This needs to be `input[i] * 2`, and you also need to *store* that value. Right now, you have two unrelated statements: `input * 2`, which (if it were correct) would compute the value and discard it. Then (and again, your syntax is in correct, you need `()` not `[]` here) `output.push[input]` would append the original value to `output`.

`[]` is for accessing an element in an array, and `()` is for invoking a function. `push` is a function. The line could be correctly written as:

```
output.push(input[i] * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few errors here;

Your for loop condition makes sure that i is *equal to* the length of the array, not less than it.  Unless your input array is empty the loop will never run.

`for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)`

You're checking if *input* (the array) is divisible by 2, not if the element inside of input is.

`if(input[i] % 2 === 1)`

You're also performing a math operation against the array object, not the element in the array, and you're not persisting it anywhere.

`var multiplied = input[i] * 2;`

You're calling the push method of the output array as an array, not as a function call.

`output.push(multiplied);`